# PHP/MYSQL/ XHTML FORM. How to update multi row table at once?

Tags: php, sql

I have following example of the PHP/SQL which worked perfectly when editing one row & saving changes.

It is working based on POST/GET method - where URL is setting up which row ID to edit / save.

`form -> post id & live values`

`seperate php file -> get 'id' and change row with this 'id'.`

```
<?php

session_name('users');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

if(!$_SESSION['id']) {
    header ("Location: index.php"); 
}


//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }

    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$id = clean($_POST['id']);
$usr2 = $_SESSION['usr'];
$live = (isset($_POST['live']))?1:0;
$updated = date("F j, Y, g:i a",time()+60*60);
$title = clean($_POST['title']);
$content = clean($_POST['content']);

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "UPDATE table SET live = '$live' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']). "'  ";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
echo mysql_error();

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: notes.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");

}

?>
```

My question is how to update multiple rows table/form like **[this one](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/Hf2KY/)**?

Comment: 2 little things.  1) For your cookie, put in the result of that equation and comment what it is doing.  No need doing that calculation every load.  2) Is there a reason why you aren't using a BEGIN - COMMIT/ROLLBACK?  You might want to do that incase it does fail.

Comment: @afuzzyllama - reason is I'm just starting to work with PHP/ MYSQL. I'm not aware of all of the options.

Comment: @afuzzyllama - cookie is set as 'remeber me' field - part of the `login` system. Not the part of the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is with a simple [for loop](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php).

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    // You didn't provide the names of the fields, so you will need to validate them here yourself.
    // I usually name them with a prefix, like somefield_3, and then I can use substr() to determine if the field is the one I'm looking for.

    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE whatever SET somefield=1 WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($key) . ";");

    //etc., etc.
}
```

Since you are only setting one boolean field, you could also do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET live=1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

But I'd recommend doing the loop, since you will inevitably need to update other fields at some point with this query.

Comment: the number of rows is unspecific. Can you give an example of using for loop in this example?

Comment: What in our case `somefield=1` will stand for? Does it mean `somefield=1 in the row of THIS ROW ID` ?

Comment: `somefield` in your case would be `live`